# Oracle: associate a date with the earliest in a list without reuse

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to match a request with the *earliest* response that follows it.  The UI doesn't enforce one request to one response, unfortunately.

Requests:

```
ENC_ID  CONTACT EVENT_TIME
13991333    1   08/13/2012 22:00:36
13991333    1   08/13/2012 22:25:21
13991333    1   08/13/2012 22:26:14
13991333    1   08/13/2012 22:36:42
13991333    2   08/13/2012 22:29:40
```

Responses:

```
ENC_ID  CONTACT EVENT_TIME
13991333    1   08/13/2012 22:25:40
13991333    1   08/13/2012 22:29:31
13991333    1   08/13/2012 22:30:47
13991333    1   08/13/2012 22:31:35
13991333    1   08/13/2012 22:31:49
13991333    2   08/13/2012 22:31:14
```

Desired:

```
ENC_ID  CONTACT REQ_EVENT_TIME  RES_EVENT_TIME
13991333    1   08/13/2012 22:00:36 08/13/2012 22:25:40
13991333    1   08/13/2012 22:25:21 08/13/2012 22:29:31
13991333    1   08/13/2012 22:26:14 08/13/2012 22:30:47
13991333    1   08/13/2012 22:36:42 
13991333    2   08/13/2012 22:29:40 08/13/2012 22:31:14
```

Rules:

- if a response is associated with a request, it **can't** be associated with another.
- it's acceptable to have a request without a response, but not the reverse

My query creates a Cartesian product:

```
SELECT  RQ.ENC_ID, RQ.CONTACT, RQ.EVENT_TIME REQ_EVENT_TIME,
        RS.EVENT_TIME RES_EVENT_TIME
FROM    RQ
LEFT OUTER JOIN RS ON RQ.ENC_ID=RS.ENC_ID
  AND RQ.CONTACT=RS.CONTACT
  AND RS.EVENT_TIME>RQ.EVENT_TIME
```

I've been experimenting with the LEAD() function, but have not be able to get it to work as desired.

Comment: What happens, or what do you want to have happen, if two responses are logged during the same second?

Comment: It isn't likely to happen, so choosing a convenient value is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t1(ENC_ID, CONTACT, EVENT_TIME) as(
  select 13991333,    1,   '08/13/2012 22:00:36' from dual union all
  select 13991333,    1,   '08/13/2012 22:25:21' from dual union all
  select 13991333,    1,   '08/13/2012 22:26:14' from dual union all
  select 13991333,    1,   '08/13/2012 22:36:42' from dual union all
  select 13991333,    2,   '08/13/2012 22:29:40' from dual
),
t2(ENC_ID,CONTACT,EVENT_TIME) as(
  select 13991333,    1,   '08/13/2012 22:25:40' from dual union all
  select 13991333,    1,   '08/13/2012 22:29:31' from dual union all
  select 13991333,    1,   '08/13/2012 22:30:47' from dual union all
  select 13991333,    1,   '08/13/2012 22:31:35' from dual union all
  select 13991333,    1,   '08/13/2012 22:31:49' from dual union all
  select 13991333,    2,   '08/13/2012 22:31:14' from dual
)
select enc_id
     , contact
     , req
     , min(res) resp
  from (select q.enc_id
             , q.contact
             , q.req
             , case  
                 when resp > req then nth_value(q.resp, q.gid) over(partition by q.enc_id, q.contact, gid order by q.req, q.gid)
               end res
         from (select t1.enc_id
                    , t1.contact
                    , t1.event_time req
                    , dense_rank() over (partition by t1.enc_id, t1.contact order by t1.event_time) gid
                    , t2.event_time resp
                 from t1
                 left outer join t2
                   on (t1.enc_id = t2.enc_id   and
                       t1.contact = t2.contact)
                order by 1,2,3,5
               ) q
         )
group by enc_id
       , contact
       ,  req
order by enc_id
       , contact
       ,  req
```

Result:

```
 ENC_ID    CONTACT     REQ                 RESP
---------- ----------  ------------------- -------------------
  13991333          1  08/13/2012 22:00:36 08/13/2012 22:25:40
  13991333          1  08/13/2012 22:25:21 08/13/2012 22:29:31
  13991333          1  08/13/2012 22:26:14 08/13/2012 22:30:47
  13991333          1  08/13/2012 22:36:42 
  13991333          2  08/13/2012 22:29:40 08/13/2012 22:31:14
```

What we are doing here is indexing groups of requests using `dense_rank` analytical function:

```
select t1.enc_id
     , t1.contact
     , to_date(t1.event_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') req
     , dense_rank() over (partition by t1.enc_id, t1.contact order by to_date(t1.event_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) gid
     , to_date(t2.event_time, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') resp
  From t1
  left outer join t2
    on (t1.enc_id = t2.enc_id   and
        t1.contact = t2.contact)
 order by 1,2,3,5
```

Result:

```
  ENC_ID    CONTACT REQ                        GID RESP
---------- ---------- ------------------- ---------- -------------------
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:00:36          1 08/13/2012 22:25:40
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:00:36          1 08/13/2012 22:29:31
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:00:36          1 08/13/2012 22:30:47
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:00:36          1 08/13/2012 22:31:35
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:00:36          1 08/13/2012 22:31:49
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:25:21          2 08/13/2012 22:25:40
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:25:21          2 08/13/2012 22:29:31
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:25:21          2 08/13/2012 22:30:47
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:25:21          2 08/13/2012 22:31:35
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:25:21          2 08/13/2012 22:31:49
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:26:14          3 08/13/2012 22:25:40
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:26:14          3 08/13/2012 22:29:31
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:26:14          3 08/13/2012 22:30:47
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:26:14          3 08/13/2012 22:31:35
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:26:14          3 08/13/2012 22:31:49
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:36:42          4 08/13/2012 22:25:40
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:36:42          4 08/13/2012 22:29:31
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:36:42          4 08/13/2012 22:30:47
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:36:42          4 08/13/2012 22:31:35
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:36:42          4 08/13/2012 22:31:49
  13991333          2 08/13/2012 22:29:40          1 08/13/2012 22:31:14
```

And then picking nth value of response according to the index of group of requests. So, for the first group of requests it will be the first value of the response time in the group, for the second group of requests it will be the second value of the response time in the group and so forth.

---

**Update** (mimic behavior of nth_value analytical function for 10g)

```
SQL> with t1(ENC_ID, CONTACT, EVENT_TIME) as(
  2    select 13991333,    1,   '08/13/2012 22:00:36' from dual union all
  3    select 13991333,    1,   '08/13/2012 22:25:21' from dual union all
  4    select 13991333,    1,   '08/13/2012 22:26:14' from dual union all
  5    select 13991333,    1,   '08/13/2012 22:36:42' from dual union all
  6    select 13991333,    2,   '08/13/2012 22:29:40' from dual
  7  ),
  8  t2(ENC_ID,CONTACT,EVENT_TIME) as(
  9    select 13991333,    1,   '08/13/2012 22:25:40' from dual union all
 10    select 13991333,    1,   '08/13/2012 22:29:31' from dual union all
 11    select 13991333,    1,   '08/13/2012 22:30:47' from dual union all
 12    select 13991333,    1,   '08/13/2012 22:31:35' from dual union all
 13    select 13991333,    1,   '08/13/2012 22:31:49' from dual union all
 14    select 13991333,    2,   '08/13/2012 22:31:14' from dual
 15  ),
 16  t3 as
 17  (
 18  select z.*
 19       , row_number() over (partition by enc_id, contact, req order by req) rn
 20    from (
 21    select t1.enc_id
 22         , t1.contact
 23         , t1.event_time req
 24         , dense_rank() over (partition by t1.enc_id, t1.contact order by t1.event_time) gid
 25         , t2.event_time resp
 26      from t1
 27      left outer join t2
 28        on (t1.enc_id = t2.enc_id   and
 29            t1.contact = t2.contact)
 30      order by 1,2,3,5
 31    ) z
 32  )
 33  select enc_id , contact, req, min(resp) resp
 34    from (
 35           select q.enc_id
 36                , q.contact
 37                , q.req
 38                , case
 39                    when min(case rn when gid then resp end) over(partition by enc_id, contact, req order by req) > req
 40                    then min(case rn when gid then resp end) over(partition by enc_id, contact, req order by req)
 41                 end resp
 42            from t3 q
 43         )
 44  group by enc_id
 45         , contact
 46         , req
 47  order by enc_id
 48         , contact
 49         , req
 50  ;

Result:


    ENC_ID    CONTACT REQ                 RESP
---------- ---------- ------------------- -------------------
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:00:36 08/13/2012 22:25:40
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:25:21 08/13/2012 22:29:31
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:26:14 08/13/2012 22:30:47
  13991333          1 08/13/2012 22:36:42 
  13991333          2 08/13/2012 22:29:40 08/13/2012 22:31:14
```

Comment: It appears that the `NTH_VALUE` function doesn't exist in 10g.

Comment: Pretty darn tricky solution!  Now if I can just find a work-around for 10g.

Comment: Is there a reason for choosing `DENSE_RANK`?  `row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.ENC_ID, T1.CONTACT, t2.event_time ORDER BY T1.EVENT_TIME)` calculates a similar value.

Comment: @craig I'm sorry for neglecting that fact that the question was tagged with 10g tag. I've updated the answer. Take a look at it.

Comment: Had to make a minor revision: `row_number() over (partition by enc_id, contact, req order by RESP) rn` instead of `row_number() over (partition by enc_id, contact, req order by req) rn`.  In any case, it worked great!  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close... try this:

```
SELECT  RQ.ENC_ID, RQ.CONTACT, RQ.EVENT_TIME REQ_EVENT_TIME,
        min(RS.EVENT_TIME) RES_EVENT_TIME
FROM    RQ
LEFT OUTER JOIN RS ON RQ.ENC_ID=RS.ENC_ID
  AND RQ.CONTACT=RS.CONTACT
  AND RS.EVENT_TIME>RQ.EVENT_TIME
GROUP BY RQ.ENC_ID, RQ.CONTACT, RQ.EVENT_TIME
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work.  It assigned `08/13/2012 22:25:40` to `08/13/2012 22:00:36` and `08/13/2012 22:25:21`.

Comment: ahh... so in the rules.. "if a response is associated with a request, it can be associated with another" should be "can't"

Comment: np.. that just makes this much harder!  :)